# Are there vulnerabilities in using an AES encrypted token for authorization

Tags: encryption, authorization, aes

We are currently implementing our authorization to a restricted resource by encrypting specific information and the password given to create a token using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encryption with a 128bit private key known only to the server.

Inside this token we place

- hash of password(sha-512 and a random salt of 64 bytes)
- expiry date
- valid flag (boolean)
- creation date timestamp

The server then encrypts this information using its private key and passes it to the client.

The client requests the restricted resource and presents this token to the server which decrypts it and validates the contents to provide access to a restricted resource.

We wish to do it this way to avoid keeping information regarding issued tokens on our server to avoid potential resource limitations.

Since I am not a security expert any help showing possible vulnerabilities or why this is a bad idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it necessary to pass the password instead of a hashed version? By hashed version I mean an iterated HAMC function such as PBKDF2, password_hash, bcrypt, etc. Note that the key will be known only to the attracker whogains admin access.

Comment: Good point the only reason we pass the password is to send it through the same code as the initial password hashing used on initial authentication but I will look at that.

Comment: Just changed it to keep the hash in the token instead and compare the hashes directly once a token is received thanks for the feedback. Password hashing is done using sha-512 and a random salt of 64 bytes

Comment: Thanks for the feedback zaph. Currently in our system there is no concept of a user authentication and only access authorization through a password configured by a system admin. In our case password hashing was only added to avoid storing plain text but if an intruder acquires access to our system they would gain access to the resources anyway making the password redundant. Some of the hashing things you mentioned however could be useful when placing it in the token.

Comment: If you would like to add your suggestions as an answer I will accept it since we it would be useful for others in a similar situation to us and seems the most secure route in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send the hashed version for comparison.

Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as PBKDF2 (aka Rfc2898DeriveBytes), password_hash/password_verify, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

See [Toward Better Password Requirements](http://www.slideshare.net/jim_fenton/toward-better-password-requirements) by Jim Fenton.

[DRAFT NIST Special Publication 800-63B Digital Authentication Guideline](
https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html)

NIST’s new password rules – what you need to know:
https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/08/18/nists-new-password-rules-what-you-need-to-know/  by Sophos